# Pandas incorrectly reading csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, encoder, csvreader

I was trying to read one csv file using;

```
df= pd.read_csv('Diff_Report.csv',on_bad_lines='skip',encoding='cp1252',index_col=None)
```

Input Example

[image]

But the code outputs as in the following screenshot. Why is it happening like this?

Output

[image]

Comment: Does your file look exactly as shown in "Input Example" i.e. separated by "|" or did you format it for display purpose?

Comment: What do you see if you open your file with text editor? It is possible that you saved your file in excel and now it is no more text CSV.

Comment: Don’t post images. Edit your question and post the actual text of the csv

Answer (score 0):

@Ammu07

Try using pd.read_excel()

**Solution 1: -**
It looks like you are displaying the first 5 rows of **df2**

**Solution 2: -**
Check if it is in another encoding or just utf encoding.

**Solution 3: -**
CSV files are separated by commas, but maybe your data contains a comma, which should be cleared.

**Solution 4: -**
Check if your data is exactly like the input or if it is separated by commas.

**Tip: - Try adding index_col as id.**

Comment: Which part of this is the "solution" and what's just a "Tip"? Is "Try using pd.read_excel()" a "solution?"